# How to resolve 'AttachAddon is not a constructor' error on Chrome?

Tags: xtermjs

Just struggling to get the Attach addon working.  The main xterm (4.4.0) comes up fine, but the Chrome browser Javascript console reports 'Uncaught TypeError:  AttachAddon is not a constructor' when I try to reference the addon.   The webserver is golang/echo, and I pull in the xterm.js and xterm-addon-attach.js from the packages as follows:

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="xterm.css" />
      <script src="xterm.js"></script>
      <script src="xterm-addon-attach.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="terminal"></div>
      <script>

        var term = new window.Terminal();

        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));

        ws = new WebSocket('ws://example.net:8080/ws')

        const attachAddon = new AttachAddon(ws);
        term.loadAddon(attachAddon);

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Can anyone help to point out what I've done wrong?

Also the examples in the docs where I took this from doesn't have the term.open() call, so how would the Terminal instance know what element to attach to?  Eg at https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/tree/master/addons/xterm-addon-attach

Many thanks in advance

Andy

Update:

I changed the HTML to include the import statements, as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="xterm.css" />
      <script src="xterm.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="terminal"></div>
      <script type="module"> 
        import { AttachAddon } from "./xterm-addon-attach.js";

        var term = new window.Terminal();

        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));

        ws = new WebSocket('ws://boundstone.dynamic-dns.net:8080/ws');

        const attachAddon = new AttachAddon(ws);
        term.loadAddon(attachAddon);

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

but the Chrome console now reports:    "The requested module './xterm-addon-attach.js' does not provide an export named 'AttachAddon'".   The webserver serves the script with content type application/javascript, and the Chrome console recognises the structure of the AttachAddon as a Webpack it seems.

I'm afraid I'm not familiar as I clearly should be with JS modules.  The web server for my project is not (and can't be) Node, but does that make a difference?

Many thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: The addons are made for ES6 imports, thus will not work out of the box with old school <script> tags. See https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/  for some background on ES6 imports.

Comment: Thanks very much, I checked out the link and made some changes, as appended to the edited first post above.  It now seems to pull in the module but the Chrome console says that AttachAddon isn't exported by the xterm-addon-attach.js module?  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Well you can use normal <script> as before, but have to grab the the ctor with `new AttachAddon.AttachAddon()`. If in doubt look at what gets exported. In general its easier to handle this with a bundler like webpack.

Comment: @jerch Perfect, thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me. The only thing you have to do is use `AttachAddon` twice as shown below using the OP's example.  That's the only trick to getting it working.  I am also using the `fit` addon and it was the same thing with that.

```
<!doctype html>


<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="xterm.css" />
      <script src="xterm.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="terminal"></div>
      <script> 

        var term = new window.Terminal();

        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));

        ws = new WebSocket('ws://boundstone.dynamic-dns.net:8080/ws');

        const attachAddon = new AttachAddon.AttachAddon(ws);
        term.loadAddon(attachAddon);

      </script>
    </body>
```